# accessing the array in stack will it be a performance hit

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory, stack-memory

just now i was stumped whether there is a performance hit in accessing a array initialized in the stack over a array initialized in the heap.

Example

```
void access(int *pointer){

}

int main(){

int array [] = {6,5,4};

access(array);

}
```

Vs

```
void access(int *pointer){

}

int main(){

int *array  =  new int[3];

access(array);

}
```

What i really want to know is whether is it possible to have direct access to the starting point of the array in the stack ?

Comment: This seems to be micro-optimization. I think the difference is not that significant to be concerned about.

Answer (score 4):

This is micro-optimisation.  The overall performance will typically be dominated by much bigger effects, such as whether the required data is in the CPU cache or not.

I strongly recommend reading [*What every programmer should know about memory*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22What+Every+Programmer+Should+Know+About+Memory%22). It's fairly heavy (and slightly out-of-date now), but it's fantastically comprehensive.